# Reading a string variable "NaN" in NetLogo

Tags: nan, netlogo

Why do I obtain :

```
observer> show count patches with [pcolor = green and ID-polygon = "NaN"]
observer: 0
```

While I have one patch with [pcolor = green and ID-polygon = "NaN"] in my landscape ?

[image]

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `NaN` isn't a string. It's "not a number", which is a numeric value which is supposed to be impossible to obtain in NetLogo.

Are you using the GIS extension?

One way you could get `NaN` is if you're using an extension that doesn't following the usual NetLogo rule disallowing `NaN` values. The GIS extension is one such extension. See http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.1.0/docs/gis.html#gis:raster-sample for details, including sample code for detecting `NaN` values. (You could encapsulate the logic for this in a procedure.)

Comment: Yes, I am using GIS extension.